# Use FixedColumns and Buttons in DT table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a shiny app with a datatable made with `{DT}`. Here, I used `server = FALSE` to download the whole table (and not only the rows displayed) in Excel file:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$test <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      cor(mtcars),
      extensions = c('Buttons', 'FixedColumns'), 
      options = list(
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons = c('excel', 'csv'),
        scrollX = TRUE
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would also like to fix the first column. However, adding `fixedColumns = TRUE` breaks the display of the first column:

```
  output$test <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      cor(mtcars),
      extensions = c('Buttons', 'FixedColumns'), 
      options = list(
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons = c('excel', 'csv'),
        scrollX = TRUE,
        fixedColumns = TRUE
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
```

I want to have these three features:

- download the whole table (not just the rows displayed) with the button
- scroll horizontally
- fix the first column

Is there a way to obtain these three features at the same time?

Comment: changing fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 2) seems to work well

Comment: Turns out the issue was with RStudio (I have `v.1.3.959`) because my code works well if I run the app in browser

Comment: This problem was reported in [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7423), not solved for now.